# Adding a factor variable to a data frame

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have a data frame "books" with a numeric variable "price." I want to create a new factor variable called "affordable" with two levels: "yes" and "no." When price is greater than 100, affordable is equal to "no." When price is less than 100, affordable is equal to "yes." How do I create this variable and add it to my data frame?

This is where I'm stuck:

```
books$affordable <- ifelse(books$price > 100, "no", "yes")
```

Comment: What have you done till now? Please share your code.

Comment: Some clues to get you started: `?ifelse` and `?factor`. And you'll need to decide how to handle the case where `price` equals 100.

Comment: Your price is way to high you need to cut it... them bricks is way to hot you need to... `cut()` it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: or. actually, `split()` it, since you want it according to a logical test, rather than some distribution.. but i can't think of a good song for that.

Comment: This is where I'm stuck:  books$affordable <- ifelse(books$price > 100, "no", "yes")

Comment: put that up in the body of your question :)

Answer (score 0):

OPs initial code:

```
books$affordable <- ifelse(books$price > 100, "no", "yes")
```

This should produce a character vector, with `"no"` for cases where the test evaluates to `TRUE`, i.e., it's expensive, and `"yes"` otherwise. Unless you're not telling us something about your data:

```
class(books$affordable)
# [1] "character"
```

You want a factor. So do this:

```
books$affordable <- factor(ifelse(books$price > 100, "no", "yes"))
```

Check

```
class(books$affordable)
levels(books$affordable)
```

Note that your levels will be ordered with `"no"` first, and `"yes"` second. That may be what you want, but may not.